# Specflow getting modal window takes a lot of time

Tags: c#, wpf, automated-tests, white-framework, teststack

I am currently writing autotests for a WPF application and faced a problem that getting the window that does not exist takes a lot of time (at least 1 minute on each autotest which is unacceptable).

I have a file saving dialog window that is sometimes opened. In order to not disturb other scenarios, I have to close such window at teardown.

The problem is that this if such window does not exist (for ex. it was closed) trying to get it takes at least a minute on each scenario. Is it possible to make it perform better?

```
public Window SavePrintOutputWindow
    {
        get
        {
            try
            {
                var printingScreen = MainScreen.ScreenWindow.ModalWindow("Printing");
                var saveOutputWindow = printingScreen.ModalWindow("Save Print Output As");
                return saveOutputWindow;
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {

                return null;
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: So what's taking all the time in the code you posted? Finding the window? Catching the exception?

Comment: it is better to check `if (object != null)` instead of try catch for doing so

Comment: @stuartd The line where it tries to find the window "Printing".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Getting window using `Get<WindowedAppScreen>("Printing", InitializeOption.NoCache)` was also slow.
Solved it using info from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5712930/c-sharp-how-to-get-handle-over-a-specific-window-using-user32-dll).

There was no need for measuring exact performance but it works fast enough for me.

Now my code looks like this:

```
[DllImport("user32.dll", SetLastError = true)]
static extern IntPtr FindWindow(string lpClassName, string lpWindowName);
public Window SavePrintOutputWindow
{
    get
    {
        try
        {
            IntPtr hWnd = FindWindow(null, "Save Print Output As");
            if (hWnd == IntPtr.Zero)
            {
                 return null;
            }
            var printingScreen = MainScreen.ScreenWindow.ModalWindow("Printing");
            var saveOutputWindow = printingScreen.ModalWindow("Save Print Output As");
            return saveOutputWindow;
        }
        catch
        {
            return null;
        }
    }
}
```

Hope it helps somebody.